# How can I obtain an attached file from a record using the C# REST web services

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to retrieve an attached file (or files) from a record in Acumatica.  I'm using the following example:

https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=b1bc82ee-ae6b-442a-a369-863d98f14630

I've attached a file to the demo inventory stock item "AACOMPUT01".

Most of the code runs as expected, but when it gets to the code line:

```
JArray jFiles = jItem.Value<JArray>("files");
```

it returns null for the jFiles JArray - as if there are no files attached.
Is there something wrong with this example - or something I need to add to get it to work?

I'm using 2021 R1 (21.107.0023), and the endpoint is default 20.200.001...

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a GET request on `StockItem` endpoint with the `expand files` option:
http://localhost/Acumatica/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem/AACOMPUT01?$expand=files

This returns the files array:

```
"files": [
    {
        "id": "bdb9534c-6aa9-41fa-a65d-3119e32b0fe5",
        "filename": "Stock Items (AACOMPUT01)\\AACOMPUT01.jpg",
        "href": "/Acumatica/entity/Default/20.200.001/files/bdb9534c-6aa9-41fa-a65d-3119e32b0fe5"
    }
```

Use the `href` URL parameter value to issue the GET request which returns the file content:
http://localhost/Acumatica/entity/Default/20.200.001/files/bdb9534c-6aa9-41fa-a65d-3119e32b0fe5

[image]

Comment: I'm working in C# - I don't make raw REST calls.   I'd need to see how this relates to the example code provided in the Acumatica page I showed...

Comment: A REST call remains a REST call, the programming language used to compile the client doesn't matter. My answer is straight from the page you linked to. I'm guessing the 'expand files' option was omitted in the request URL.

Comment: If you're having difficulty making REST requests please add the requests in your question.

Comment: No.  A REST call is not a REST call, if it's presented in a C# wrapper like the example for C# shows.  The syntax is completely different.  What I need is the proper syntax to do what you're telling me to do.

Comment: The link in your question is to Acumatica Documentation for REST web service. Are you using REST to connect to Acumatica? I do not see the Acumatica C# wrapper mentioned in Acumatica documentation. The wrapper is available without support on GitHub: https://github.com/Acumatica/AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp

Comment: If you are referring to 'GetByKeys' example, this is a basic REST call and not using the wrapper. In that case I'm guessing the 'expand files' option was not passed in the 'parameters' variable when calling 'GetByKeys'.

Comment: I added a picture to my answer, maybe that will be easier to understand. Make sure that you are passing parameter '$expand=files' in the REST request.

Comment: I'm assuming you scrolled down on the example to where the C# code is.  Anyway, I modified the code to add the parameter you mentioned as  follows:

string stockItem = rs.GetByKeys("StockItem", inventoryID, "expand=files");

This didn't seem to make any difference.  I still get a null for the jFiles JArray...

Comment: Double check the final URL, attach a debugger or use traces. For example, I suggested '$expand=files', does the URL used match exactly? The C# REST client example should be like all others, it has to compute a URL. Check that URL to make sure it works with Postman. var url = _acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/Default/18.200.001/" + 
          entityName + "/" + keys + "?" + parameters;

Comment: Yes I'm referring to C# example on documentation page. If you are indeed the GitHub wrapper (URL below), my comment is not applicable.  github.com/Acumatica/AcumaticaRESTAPIClientForCSharp

Comment: My apologies, Hugh.  I didn't put the '$' before the 'expand=files' parameter.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, for most REST API the '$' is not required. Not sure this follows standard but Acumatica API does require it.